# How can i add a bibliography with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to generate a .docx file from rmd with knitr/pandoc within RStudio. But I am receiving the followinfg erroe messge  status 83 and I can't solve the status message. Any suggestions or help would be nice. Thank you very much. Sebastian

```
system(paste0("pandoc -o ", name, ".docx ", name, ".md --bibliography sukstorf.bib"))
pandoc-citeproc: "stdin" (line 421, column 2):
unexpected "O"
expecting "c", "C", "p", "P", "s" or "S"
pandoc.exe: Error running filter pandoc-citeproc
Warning message:
running command 'pandoc -o hr-statistik-mit-r.docx hr-statistik-mit-r.md --bibliography sukstorf.bib' had status 83
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you need `--bibliography sukstorf.bib` to be `--bibliography=sukstorf.bib`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the tip. The Problem is solved. It was a "'" in one of my BibTex-Keys. After I've changed the Key everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue "bibliography...had status 83": it turns out that it was a syntax error in one of the entries in the .bib file.  I found it by removing entries from the .bib one at a time and re-knitting until I hit the one generating the error.